# PHP - Use multiple values in foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have the two PHP loops as below:

```
foreach ($directData as $key => $val) {
            echo $val;
            echo "|"; //Just for the visual.
}

foreach ($sdata as $key => $val) {
            echo $val;
            echo "|"; //Just for the visual.
}
```

Which output:

`5|5|5|10|10|10|0|` and the second:    `2|2|2|5|5|5|20|`

My question is, how can I combine these two result (add them) and print it out like above?

So, it would be:

```
7|7|7|15|15|15|20
```

Comment: do arrays have the same keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
php > $a = [1, 2, 3];
php > $b = [4, 5, 6];
php > $c = array_map(function($x, $y){ return $x + $y; }, $a, $b);
php > print_r($c);
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 7
    [2] => 9
)
php > print_r(implode($c, '|') . '|');
5|7|9|
```

Answer (score 0):

Broken down for better readability, this will sum them into `$new` array.

`array_map` will iterate through both given arrays and apply the callback function to both of the arrays at their current indexes. The callback function will sum the values of at current indexes.

```
$new=array_map(
    function(){
        return array_sum(func_get_args());
    },
    $directData, $sdata
);

$out= '';
foreach ($new as $key => $val)
    $out .= $val.'|';
echo rtrim($out,'|');
```

Comment: Ty for spotting it, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If each index corresponds in the arrays

```
   $rezult = array();   

   for($i=0;$i<count($directData);$i++){
      $rezult[] = $directData[$i] + $sdata[$i];
   }

   echo join("|",$rezult);
```

Answer (score 0):

in simple way you can do it like:

```
$finalData = array_map(function () {
    return array_sum(func_get_args());
}, $directData, $sdata );
print_r($finalData );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that uses the iterators that all PHP arrays have.

```
/**
 * Use the iterator that all PHP arrays have.
 *
 * Check both arrays for having entries.
 */

$listOut = array(); // output in here

while (current($listA) !== false && current($listB) !== false) {
    $listOut[] = current($listA) + current($listB);
    next($listA);
    next($listB);
}
```

*Input:*

```
$listA = array(5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 0);
$listB = array(2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 20, );
```

*Output*

```
Array
(
    [0] => 7
    [1] => 7
    [2] => 7
    [3] => 15
    [4] => 15
    [5] => 15
    [6] => 20
)

7| 7| 7| 15| 15| 15| 20
```

Comment: add for completeness of ways of processing arays.